# ASP.Net development with pure AJAX architecture

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, architecture

Do you think developing a ASP.Net site, with pure jQuery, AJAX and JSON web service calls being setup on each page is a good idea? (Code-behind has been keep to minimum, everything is client-side scripting if possible)

```
//on .ready()
$(function() {
    //call web service to initialize page
    $.ajax({
        url: "myService.asmx/DoSomething",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(message){ 
            //render html page with jTemplates plugin
        }
    });
});
```

I'm in the middle of development using this architecture, and start to get concern because I'm new to this and I can't be sure whether I'm doing the right thing..

Is this approach favourable than the other (Or this is definitely BAD)? Why and why not?

Comment: what do you do with the website? do the search engines matter? if so, better to load html and do other things with ajax, like posting a form

Comment: search engines don't matter here.. it is an administration site that is used by a closed group of people to manage and support another public site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built an entire interactive Facebook game on JavaScript. I used an MVC framework for JavaScript(backbone) and the communication between front end and back end was purely rest calls requesting and submitting information, the back end was PHP we used the MVC, CodeIgniter framweork. It took a lot of planning but it was definitely do able.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible and for that reason, you may even use plain XHTML. But a lot of client-side code might cause security to be weak. The other viewpoints might be ease of development and maintenance of the code. There is no standard framework on top of ASP.NET in this line as of now. MVC or MVVM are all based on server side codes.